# Please help me identify this bike (Staiger MTB)

Tags: identify-this-bike

Please, help me identify (i wanna know "the model") this bike you see at the picture.

[image]

Thank you so much, guys!

Comment: What is the brand of the taillight on the rack?

Comment: Frisbee,oh just crap lights.Just need to find out the model and features of that bike.Thank you.

Comment: Thanks,  I am looking for a (crap) light like that for my rack.

Comment: A photo from the right side of the bike is better, it shows more detail of the transmission area.  What else is written on the bike other than "Staiger"  ?  Is it made from steel, aluminium, or something else?  When did you get it?  Where from?  Was it new when you got it?  Can you ask the previous owner for further information?

Answer (score 1):

Initial answer:  Google says that **Staiger** is a German bike company.  http://www.staiger-fahrrad.de/

Curiously, none of their current range has any resemblance to your frame shape - that weird shortened toptube is quite unusual.